# DDEV Prestashop database connection

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, ddev

I want to install a Prestashop with DDEV, but I can't connect to database.

I tried 127.0.0.1:32775 and localhost:32775, with "db" as user/db/password
But I get this error:

```
Database Server is not found. Please verify the login, password and server fields (DbPDO)
```

Database is up and running, connection via commandline is working:

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=32775 --user=db --password=db --database=db
```

Project information:

- PrestaShop 1.7.6.2 Installer (I first tried github/composer installation - error, then zip download with wizard - same error)
- ddev version v1.11.2
- DDEV project type: php
- Host: MacOS 10.15.1

DDEV config.yaml - changes to default: router_http(s)_port

```
APIVersion: v1.11.2
name: prestatest
type: php
docroot: ""
php_version: "7.2"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
router_http_port: "880"
router_https_port: "8443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
mariadb_version: "10.2"
nfs_mount_enabled: false
provider: default
use_dns_when_possible: true
timezone: ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ddev describe` will show you the db connection information.

Host: db
User: db
Password: db
Database: db

Mostly people forget the hostname configuration.

Comment: I used them already, still the error, I updated the original post

Comment: Your original post still shows you using 127.0.0.1 as the host, you want to use 'db'. That's the name of the host from within the container.

Comment: Yay, it works! 
Connection from WITHIN the container, didn't expect that, but hey, it works!

Comment: Yes, everything about the functionality of ddev is stuff that happens inside the containers. So you're telling the webserver how to access the dbserver, and both are inside docker containers.